# VirtualBox nesting: Possible to install VirtualBox on a VirtualBox Guest

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I have a host machine that has virtualBox installed, and a guest OS virtual machine is created on it.

I want to test installing virtualBox on that guest OS for training purposes, so this means that I'll be installing VirtualBox on a machine that's actually a guest image running using VirtualBox itself. Do you see any problems with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the bad performance is completly possible to Install a Virtual Box virtual machine inside another virtual machine.

Due VirtualBox doesnt virtualize Intel VT-X or AMD-V in its virtual machines and the VirtualBox requires those technolgies for run 64 virtual machines, the second Virtual Machine should be of 32 bits.

Comment: It did give me problems with a linux guest which had to do with symbol name collisions between the vboxdrv and vboxguest kernel modules. Did you guys actually manage to do it?

Comment: Do other hypervisors support this? I require 64-bit guests on my main guest VM.